# Azure App configuration Deploying Event Subscription failed due to "Webhook validation handshake failed"

Tags: azure, webhooks, azure-eventgrid, azure-app-configuration

Hi I am trying to create an event subscription for Azure App Configuration via Portal. Endpoint Type is Webhook. The System Topic gets created successfully, but the Event Subscription Deployment fails due to "Webhook validation handshake failed for..." I tried the postman call as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/webhook-event-delivery) I don't get any validation response but a successful entry in the teams channel and status response 200, although i had to tweak the body to add a "text": ""  value. tried similar to event grid creation but still no luck. Could it be, it is expecting a validation response from teams? how do i get that setup? Any help will be highly appreciated.[image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the mentioned [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/webhook-event-delivery), the *Microsoft Teams* is not in the list of services, where their webhook endpoint code is participated in a validation handshake with Event Grid.

You should use an integrator service, for instance: [Azure Logic App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/) or [API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/) to validate and mediate an event message based on the needs.

Comment: Thank you, any examples on Azure Logic App and Ms Team integration?